# Trying to subtract a float through interfaces, doesn't seem to set it afterwards

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Title may be a little confusing but I'm gonna try and be as clear as I can

Currently in the process of making a game for a school project. I wanted to implement health and damage through interfaces because it seemed really useful to know. The code is simple.
In the Attack() method

[image]

I feed it player health and enemy damage (gameobject can be ignored since I'm still working on that part). I simply subtract the health with the damage.

The code that I feed the enemy is here.

[image]

For some reason, if I set the enemy health to 20 and damage to 3, if I Debug.Log(health) in the interface class it subtracts it, but it just doesn't want to store it after it subtracts, so it just pulls 20 again and again.

My subject teacher can't help me out right now so I'm hoping that someone miles smarter than the both of us knows why this isn't storing

Comment: Please add your code as text in the question.  The reason might be due to the confusion of reference and value types, see [Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types)

Answer (score 1):

`float` is one of many [Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) in c#.

This means whenever passing it as a parameter or assign it to a field etc it will create a new **copy** of the value.

=> The `health` within the scope of your `Attack()` method is in absolutely no way linked to the `health` field of your class with the `OnTriggerEnter` nor the `pM.health`! In general you should store your values in a single place and not in multiple places and then need to keep them all in sync all the time.

If you want these to be linked you rather want to use the [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) keyword which will basically treat a value type similar to a reference (not exactly the same though)

```
public void Attack(float damage, ref float health, GameObject bullet)
{
    health -= damage;
}
```

and then I would rather pass in

```
private void OnTriggerEnter()
{
    ...
    IFGround.Attack(damage, ref pM.health, a);
    ...
}
```

instead of storing the health value in multiple places and then have to keep them all in sync

---

If your teacher didn't catch that I would be worried ^^